# "Не надо было шевелиться" - разбор сказуемого, роль слова "было"

Tags: сказуемые

> Удивительно голое место. Только несколько минных воронок. Ни одного окопа. «Будут спрашивать, – говорю Васину, – отдувайся за двоих!» Выскакиваю из окопа и бегу. Ветер кидается мне навстречу. Трудно дышать. Впереди – воронка. Только бы добежать до неё! И тут словно плетью хлестнули по земле. Обстрел. **Не надо было шевелиться.** (Бакланов)

Последнее предложение - безличное, с составным глагольным сказуемым. В этом сказуемом основная часть - "**шевелиться**" (инфинитив), а вспомогательная часть "**(не) надо**" (слово категории состояния и частица "не").

А слово "**было**" куда отнести? Во вспомогательную часть или в именную?

Или "**было не надо**" (я слегка поменял порядок слов) - это составное именное микросказуемое, являющееся вспомогательной частью для "шевелиться"?

Последняя гипотеза навеяна [прочитанным](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_1_6) на сайте "Лицей" об осложненных типах составных сказуемых:

> Тип 3. Вспомогательная часть составного глагольного сказуемого выражена составным именным микросказуемым с модальным значением (должен, обязан, нужно, нельзя и др.) и основная часть выражена составным глагольным сказуемым (двумя инфинитивами).
>
> Осложнённое СГС = СИС + СГС
>
> *Он был вынужден начать работать.*
>
> Вспомогательная часть (**был вынужден**) – составное именное сказуемого с модальным значением и самостоятельным сказуемым быть не может. Основная часть (**начать работать**) выражена двумя инфинитивами (первый – с фазовым значением, второй – с основным лексическим значением). В другом контексте эти два глагола могут стать самостоятельным составным глагольным сказуемым (ср.: Он начал работать).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Не надо шевелиться** - составное глагольное сказуемое, вспомогательная часть выражена модальным предикативом "надо", который в настоящем времени имеет **нулевую связку.**

**Не надо было шевелиться** - составное глагольное сказуемое, вспомогательная часть выражена модальным предикативом "надо", который в прошедшем времени имеет **ненулевую связку "было"**.

**Он был вынужден начать работать** - **осложненное** составное глагольное сказуемое, **увеличенная** вспомогательная часть выражена модальным кратким прилагательным с ненулевой связкой "было" и фазовым инфинитивом "начать", далее основной глагол "работать".

Полагаю, что в этом случае рассуждения о микросказуемых или сложных (трехкомпонентных) сказуемых только затемняют смысл даже самых простых глагольных  структур.

Comment: Спасибо! Т.е. "надо" - модальный предикатив и одновременно [слово категории состояния](http://rusolimp.kopeisk.ru/morfologia/?file=112), наверное. А "было" - относится к "надо", являясь его связкой. Понятно. "Начать работать" в английской грамматике назвали бы "катенативной конструкцией" или чем-то вроде того. (0:

Comment: Слова категории состояния иначе называются предикативами. Модальные предикативы (можно, нельзя, нужно, надо, необходимо) - это предикативы  (слова категории состояния) со значением долженствования, необходимости, возможности.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Последнее предложение - безличное, с составным глагольным сказуемым. 
  В      этом сказуемом ИМЕННАЯ ЧАСТЬ - "шевелиться" (инфинитив), 
  а вспомогательная часть "(не) надо" (слово категории состояния и частица   "не").

  А слово "было" куда отнести? Во вспомогательную часть или в именную?
```

Не надо было шевелиться. - трёхчленное составное глагольное сказуемое, состоящее из двух частей: вспомогательной, выраженной категорией состояния + глагольной связкой в прош. времени, и инфинитивом, выражающим лексическое значение.

Инфинитив не именная часть, а основная.Именная - это имя, а не глагол(вот НАДО БЫЛО - сост.именное микросказуемое, верно), а инфинитив всё же глагол.

Comment: Людмила, не надо было шевелиться - СГС, внутри которого выделяется еще одно - Составное именное микросказуемое - со связкой надо было".

Comment: Людмила, а разве я сказал, что инфинитив - это СИС?

Comment: @Серж - это я написал, что инфинитив - "именная" часть - но я уже исправил, чтобы посетители сайта не путались.

Comment: А я смотрю, у вас написано, что инфинитив - СГС. Поэтому подумал, что мне адресовано.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае "было" относится к связке составного именного микросказуемого "надо было".

Ср.: Я ***должен был*** стать врачом.

В этом случае сказуемое можно представить как сочетание трёх сказуемых: составного именного (должен был), составного глагольного (должен был стать) и составного именного (стать врачом).